# Add option to google drive left panel

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Is there any way to add a custom menu option to the left panel menu (below My Drive, Shared with me, Starred, Recent) insted the More option?

Comment: Reason for rollback: unless OP confirms extensions are something he's interested in as a solution, tags shouldn't be added.

Comment: In terms of tags, neither apps-script or drive-sdk apply. This is not a programming question under the terms of StackOverflow. It is a question about a web application which belogs in http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-drive

Answer (score 1):

Not using Apps Script alone.

The only means you have available to you is via browser plugins. There will be no direct access to the drive APIs so you'll need to bring your own code. But a Chrome plugin, for example, will be able to append the section of the UI with whatever works as a web app. Apps Script might be able to act as server support.

Beware though, you are at the mercy of the labyrinth DOM that makes up most Google Apps if you try to pin a solution to it.

You can install Apps Script apps as 3rd party Drive Apps but they would exist solely as a button within the **New** button not as a separate UI item.

Comment: Wait, you edited the question's tags to fit your answer? It was (according to tags) an Apps Script question.

Comment: There isn't a way to what the questioner wants by apps script alone. With luck someone can help further, though it is in fact a little too broad. I thought tags were to aid exposure not keep score.

Comment: I agree, but I would ask OP first. As the original question stands, you answered it (maybe even edit it to specifically say "cannot be done with Apps Script")

Comment: Got it.  Thanks for the guidance.